# angular js update json on interval and update the view

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've been trying to find a solution on the internet to be able to update my $http json request on a set interval time and at the same time have it update my bindings with the new data.

I've seen some examples using $timeout but haven't been able to get it working and just wanted to know what the best approach would be for this. Also being able to update the views with the new data pulled down is something I cant seem to solve as I haven't been able to make the new request.

Here is my current build.

app.js file, this just shows the initial  fetch for the json.

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
            $scope.Days = {};

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "data.json"
            })
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.Days = data;
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // something went wrong :(
                });

        }
    ]);
```

The HTML setup:

```
<ul ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li class="date" ng-repeat-start="day in Days">
    <strong>>{{ day.Date }}</strong>
  </li>

  <li class="item" ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="item in day.Items">
    <strong>>{{ item.Name }}</strong>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve. From your example you call http async call that returns `Days` object. The `ngRepeat` directive listens on `Days` change (has private watchers) and shows up new data. What's the problem? thanks,

Comment: The json data I am requesting from the server is consistently being updated and I was under the impression I would need to set a timeout function to recall the $http to grab the updated json data and then update the current views. Maybe I'm still a little mistaken on how angular works. My apologies.

Comment: So as I understand you want to run in loop http with some delay, right?

Comment: Yes, like a poller. Requests the json every x seconds then updates the views if the data has changed.

Comment: Use $interval to get function executed after effect few mins... and fir your requirement push services are better than $ interval

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `$timeout`.

As you know the `$timeout` return promise. So when promise is resolved we can call method `myLoop` once more.

In following example we call http every 10 sec.

```
var timer;

function myLoop() {
    // When the timeout is defined, it returns a
    // promise object.
    timer = $timeout(function () {
        console.log("Timeout executed", Date.now());
    }, 10000);

    timer.then(function () {
        console.log("Timer resolved!");

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "data.json"
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Days = data;
            myLoop();
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // something went wrong :(
        });
    }, function () {
        console.log("Timer rejected!");
    });

}

myLoop();
```

*As a side note:*

When controller is destroyed be sure to call `$timeout.cancel( timer );`

```
// When the DOM element is removed from the page,
// AngularJS will trigger the $destroy event on
// the scope. 
// Cancel timeout
$scope.$on("$destroy", function (event) {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1274/)**</kbd>

Comment: Is there a benefit to using $timeout over using $interval?

Comment: @Anks In our case I think `$timeout` is better because your method is async call. Its true that the `$interval` less expensive and you can set flag to do not fire digest cycle. However in our case we fire next call only when got success callback. What happens if request failed or stuck, the `$interval`  will continue to iterate over the http call. So its your choice what is better.